# SQL Multiple Inner Joins on the same field

Tags: mysql, innodb, inner-join

I am currently working as a programmer in a small startup aiming on providing pay-per-view content online and I have been assigned to develop the metadata database for the movie catalogue

I have two main tables, **movie** and **people**, where *movie_ID* and *people_ID* are the primary keys respectively for each table. Both tables have a many-to-many relationship.

To represent different relations I am currently using link tables, for example, **actor_movie** would store the *movie_ID* and corresponding *people_ID* for each of the actors in the movie, while the **director_movie** table would store the *movie_ID* and the director(s) *people_ID*. Same goes for writer, composers and producers.

Now, my problem is that I need to craft out a query that returns all the actors, directors, producers, writers, composers, etc. etc. in one single table to be passed on the frontend Web UI as a list of all the persons involved in the movie.

I'm currently stumped as to how to create a multiple SELECT query that would JOIN all the link tables together based on the *movie_ID* and *people_ID* and then return the details of each of the person in the *people* table as well.

And example of what I have written so far is:

```
SELECT
movie.titleMovie,
people.namePeople,
FROM 
movie movie

INNER JOIN actorlinkmovie acm ON acm.idMovie = movie.idMovie
INNER JOIN people people ON people.idPeople = acm.idPeople
```

What I would like to have happen is:

```
SELECT
movie.idMovie,
movie.titleMovie,
movie.descMovie,
movie.dateMovie,
movie.runtimeMovie,
movie.langMovie,
movie.ratingMovie,
people.namePeople
FROM 
htv_movie movie

INNER JOIN htv_actorlinkmovie acm ON acm.idMovie = movie.idMovie
INNER JOIN htv_directorlinkmovie dcm ON dcm.idMovie = movie.idMovie
INNER JOIN htv_producerlinkmovie pcm ON pcm.idMovie = movie.idMovie
INNER JOIN htv_people people WHERE people.idPeople = dcm.idPeople AND people.idPeople = acm.idPeople AND people.idPeople = pcm.idPeople
```

And it should return the all the related people from a single movie.

Would like to get some input about the whole design since I'm a pretty new at designing a whole database (first time actually) and whether would this design be suitable if I need to scale up to about 5000 movies (the current company aim). This database will pretty much serve as the website's backend as well.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Temporarily worked out a dirty solution using PHP variables and a template SQL query. Looks like doing multiple inner joins wasn't that required after all. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Do you want all rows individually of each person and their context / part in or behind-the-scenes of the movie?  Or, do you want one column showing all names for "Director(s)",  "Writer(s)", "Actor(s)", etc...

Comment: I would prefer to have the multiple columns if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal like this:

> SELECT MovieName,
>   dbo.GetDirector(MovieID),
>   dbo.GetActors(MovieID),
>   dbo.GetWriter(MovieID) FROM Movie

where

- dbo.GetDirector(MovieID) is a
  function that will return directors
  in the movie.
- dbo.GetActors(MovieID) is a function
  that will return actors in the movie.
- dbo.GetWriter(MovieID) is a function
  that will return writers in the
  movie.

If there are some other tables then you can make functions for those tables as well.

Hope this helps.